# Laravel 4.2 SuperClosure: Attempted to serialize unserializable builtin class Closure

Tags: laravel, hhvm

History:

- Laravel 4.2 recently updated from 4.1 running on HHVM-stable
- This exact code worked before whatever broke broke
- Downgrading back to 4.1 didn't resolve

Whenever (apparently) an uncaught exception is thrown, the app crashes with:

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Attempted to serialize unserializable builtin class Closure$;1617701371#2$9f9bb1ee4ac7330c21e327d2b7294b9c$' 
in /home/forge/.../vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/SerializableClosure.php:78
```

It's a dickens to troubleshoot because it seems to crash during error handling, so the feedback it gives me is less than helpful.

Any idea what this is about? Am I alone with this error? Googling turns up nada and this has pretty much shut us down until I can resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that happens if you try to serialize an Exception. (In this case, outputting it via  `Log::error("...", [$e])`. Just stringify it and all is good.

Comment: I will, have to wait 2 hours :)